# Accessing C# Methods and Constructor from C++ program

Tags: c#, c++, mscorlib

Created a C# DLL to I/F with a C++ test console app program CSartTest.cpp
The C++ recognizes the class defined in the C# DLL (MtXxxxx  -- (name obviously changed))
Don't know how to instantiate the object or reference its public methods.

Here is what I have done thus far:

1. Modified the project to:
   AssemblyInfo.cs: --
   `[assembly: ComVisible(true)]`
   Signing: Project is signed
   Build:
   Project is Regressed for COM interop
2. Added an `Interface IMtXxxxx.cs` (obviously XC=XXXX is not the true name) -- Added:
   `[ComVisible(true)]`
   `[Guid ("1fd98919-18b7-4b41-9a08-c7e74f09d6bd")]`
   `[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]`
3. For the main Class added:
   `[ComVisible(true)]`
   `[Guid("e82e2cf6-67dc-4574-b579-ff1452943271")]`
   `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]`
   `[ProgId("LTA_MT.MtXxxxx. ")]`
4. Solution compiles and creates a tbl file -- `LTA.MT.tlb`
5. In the C++ project added the generated .tbl file
6. In the main program in the C++ console app -
   added:
   at the top of the file:
   `#include <tchar.h>`
   `#import "<Path to tbl file>\LTA.MT.tlb" raw_interfaces_only (path has "\" in it`
   `using namespace LTA_MT;`
   `in int main()`
   `HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);`
   `MtXxxxx *busessRules = NULL;`
   7. In Tools/Options/Debugging/Symbols -- Checked Microsoft Symbol Servers

Solution compiles and executes However:
A. Don't know how to instantiate the C# object
B. Can't seem to get IntelliSense working for object busessRules

What am I missing -- Please help -- Thanks

Googled interfacing between C++ and C# a lot -- don't fully understand all the answers I found --

Tried to include `#using <mscorlib.dll>` but got a compiling error

Thought about adding and including a header file `#include <CShartTest.h>` but that did not seem to work

As I said, not very proficient in C++ at this time -- Have not used in in decades and am very rusty.

Would like very simple step by step instructions -- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of clutter in your question, but you seem to be asking how to instantiate a COM object in C++, and the answer is simple: [`CoCreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance). Your `IID_` and `CLSID_` definitions should be imported from your `.tlb` file.

> Tried to include #using <mscorlib.dll> but got a compiling error

That's a different approach from yours, where you don't use COM objects to proxy messages between your native application and .Net, but instead you make your C++ application managed so it can directly reference your managed library. Much, much easier (and faster!).

Comment: OK -- Don't use mscorlib.dll in my technique -- Got it.

In my tbl file I have the following lines

Comment: In the tbl file I have this code:|
     _COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IMtXxxxx, __uuidof(IMtXxxxx));

     virtual HRESULT __stdcall Yyyyy ( ) = 0;
Also have this
#pragma once
#pragma pack(push, 8)

#include <comdef.h>

Do I include the include and the pragma in my C++ app?
How do I instantiate the Xxxx object in the C++ program and if I can't how to I reverence the IXxxx interface?

How do I call the Yyyy() method in the C++ app

Sorry for these ?'s but not as familiar w/ C++ as I am with C#

Thanks for your help

Comment: Figured it out  -- Added IMTXxxxx pICalc(__uuidof(MtXxxx)); statement after the 
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL); statement

pICalc now has intillisense that points to the exposed interface

Comment: Sure, cause it's a real class, but that's never going to actually run

Comment: Moved all modules called by the C# DLL into the DLL itself and got by that hurdle -- now getting a error '...System.Data.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file -- The DLL is in
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\ -- 

How do I get the C++ app to load this system DLL -- #using <System.Data.dll> did not work -- states required C++/CLI mode